# NSTimer resets UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a NSTimer that fires an `advavanceTimer:` Method constantly to update a countdown `UILabel` with the seconds left.
Meanwhile a `CMMotionManager` detects a shake gesture and moves a `UIView` object 50px to the right side or rather the animation does not persist.

The problem: the fired `advavanceTimer:` Method moves the `UIView` back to the origin position

```
-(void)startCountdownWithTimeLimit:(double)timeLimit {
    self.counter = timeLimit;

    self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(advanceTimer:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}

-(void)advanceTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
    [self setCounter:(self.counter-1)];
    self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Countdown: %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.counter]]; //if removed, everything works fine
    //... 
}

-(void)setupMotionManager{
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1;

    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
     {
         [self motionMethod:motion];
     }];
}

-(void)motionMethod:(CMDeviceMotion *)deviceMotion
{
    CMAcceleration userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
    if (fabs(userAcceleration.x) > accelerationThreshold
        || fabs(userAcceleration.y) > accelerationThreshold
        || fabs(userAcceleration.z) > accelerationThreshold)
    {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            CGRect oldFrame = self.movingView.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x+50, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
            self.movingView.frame = newFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using auto layout. Every time you set a label's text, auto layout performs layout. Thus, at that moment, the constraints come along and put everything back into the position dictated by those constraints.

Solution: don't change (animate) the *frame* of anything; change (animate) its *constraints*.

Comment: okey thanks. So is updating or animating the constraints instead of the frame a solution?

Comment: Didn't you edited it? If not I overread the solution and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry, it always takes me several edits to finish my answers.